# How to run bcp utility from root drive?

Tags: sql-server-2008, bcp

My machine does not have full SQL Server installed. The following distributable packages are installed on my machine:-

1. Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 Command Line Utilities
2. Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 Native Client

I have a batch file that runs the bcp utility. If i run this batch file from the folder where bcp.exe is sitting (...tools\binn) it works.

My dump question is if there is any way I can run the bcp utility from c:\ drive only. Right now if it run from c:\ drive it says:-

> bcp is not recognized as an internal or external command,..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to add the folder containing bcp.exe to the environment variables search path.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

You can read the bvp.exe path from registry and then simply use full path
RootKey : HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
PathKey  : SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\ClientSetup 
Key : path (String)

Answer (score 1):

Or just use the full path to the file:

```
C:\>"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\bcp" rest_of_options_here
```